# Sails.JS models not globally accessible even though Globals.JS contains models:true after upgarde from 0.12 to 1.4.3

Tags: sails.js

I previously had a Sails project version 0.12.11 & just upgraded to version 1.4.3

My global.js file is below

```
module.exports.globals = {
    _: require("lodash"),
    async: false,
    sails: true,
    services: true,
    models: true
};
```

However, I defined a User model in my api/models/User.js.

I am trying to use USER in my controller like below

UserController.js

```
Users.find({ 'username': memquery.emailid }).populate('RolesKey').exec(function (err1, res1) {
            if (err1)
            {
               return res.handleError(err1);
            } 
}
```

It is giving me Below error
**ReferenceError: Users is not defined**

How can we resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

Try to access **Users** model as `User`. Use the same name of the model file: for example: `api/models/User.js` so the model is `User`.

The other common mistake is due to some text editors that auto-import the model including a line at the beginning of the controller file, something like `const Users = require('../../api/models/Users')`.